# Did I really lose 2 reputation?

Tags: support, bug, reputation, suggested-edits

I know it has something to do with deleted posts that I've edited before but I edited another post right now but I'm not getting back the +2 reputation. Yes I have a Gold Editor badge so this means that I've made 500 suggested edits approved so I can't gain any rep. But it's still losing me some rep from deleted edits.

[Current reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2804613/puretppc?tab=reputation)

[Suggested edit just now](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4026394)

I didn't gain rep as I completed this edit just now. Did I really lose 2 rep or is it a glitch that it shows up? I can't recall losing 2 rep though.

Comment: Might a recalc solve it?

Comment: @bjb568 Users cannot trigger manual recalcs anymore.

Comment: @animuson Oh. Why not?